# PriviledgedActionException when running hadoop job from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, permissions, hadoop

I'm getting this following permission error:

> org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation  - PriviledgedActionException as:myusername (auth:SIMPLE) cause:java.io.IOException: Cannot initialize Cluster.

An error appeared when I changed in hadoop maven version to 0.23.0-cdh4b1 and after adding the package "hadoop-auth" (without him can not find the necessary classes)

In a cluster it works, but when debugging in eclipse requires additional privileges.

How can I disable checking privileges on startup from LocalJobRunner?

My OS - Ubuntu 11.10